# Why do the iphone get the network location position so fast?

Tags: ios, core-location

Iphone's core-location is so amazing for me .

I write some test codes to call the startlocationupdating function to get the position:

(void)doContinuousPositioning:(UIButton*)sender
{
    self.bPersistent = YES;

```
if (self.bPersistent) {
    _tv_Info.hidden = YES;
    _tableView.hidden = NO;
}

if (self.locationManager) {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    self.locationManager = nil;
}

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

_beginTime = [Global getTimeStamp];
[self.locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
```

results:

2017-08-29 17:13:13.081 | starttime：2017-08-29 17:13:13.052

endtime：2017-08-29 17:13:13.080

timecost：28 ms

long：113.046818, alt：21.571278

altitude: 38.528896

horizontalAccuracy: 65.000000

verticalAccuracy: 23.415365

course: -1.000000

speed: -1.000000

floor: 0

I find that the position returns back so fast no mater where you are, the fuction run time is in 60 ms or less.

And the accuracy of position is  very high also, most time it give 60 meters;

And even i move from A place to B place ,the A differs from B by 10km

The position returns back so fast also ,amazingggggggg!

i know that the first position is a network position type.

So the questions is:

How can iphone return back so fast and high network position?

In my opinion, network position sources come from cell or wifi ap;

it will spend 2ms to get  cell id   or  spend 2s to get wifi ap in phone at least.

The second question is :

Can the iphone use the cell id to calculate a high accuracy position?

or

Iphone can get the wifi ap in 20ms?

Comment: You can check the timestamp of the location you get by doing `locations.last!.timestamp` and see if it was a cached result or not. But usually the first few location callbacks are cached or too quick to be correct. 
You can log the distances between locations and verify that.

Comment: i tried to change different places(about 500m) to do the test. it seems it spend the same time . not like a cached reuslt

Answer (score 2):

> How can iphone return back so fast and high network position?

Core Location is a system service. It runs in the background and caches results. If it has a recent location, e.g. another app (or your app) has requested it recently,  it will give it almost immediately. Subsequent callbacks may give even more accurate results if those come available e.g. with a GPS lock.

60 meters resolution is not really high accuracy, it likely comes from the combined Wifi and Cell information.

> Can the iphone use the cell id to calculate a high accuracy position?

To my knowledge cell tower information is used for the most inaccurate position, Wifi information is next and the highest accuracy comes from GPS/GLONASS.

Those information sources can (and likely are) combined by Core Location for increased accuracy.

> Iphone can get the wifi ap in 20ms?

As said, Core Location is a system service, it may respond to you in 20ms, but it is impossible to know when the location data has actually been calculated and how much time it took.

Comment: Your answers explain the network position theory well，but if you work at it ,you will want to know how and when it will calculate the position . if it calculate all the time  backgroud ,it will cost more power, but after some test ,it seems not more power cost when screen off .so the core location system is mystery for me to discover;

Comment: I have worked with the API a few times. Documentation gives some details, but the inner workings, e.g. caching, are quite much a black box. To know more about it can be a good academically, but in practice I see quite little benefit in trying to find out how the black box works in different use cases and different OS versions.